# Google ReCaptcha form not sending to email

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

~I'm a complete beginner to php and coding in general.~

Problems: form not sending to email, header location works (I think), but it doesn't show the captcha validation message anymore.

I've tried my gmail, school email, and temp emails and nothing works. It used to send, but I changed a lot since then to incorporate the error/success message and don't know what went wrong. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

form:

```
<form action="formvalidation.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>first name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" for="name" minlength="3" maxlength="20" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" class="form-control" value ="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($name) ?>" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" minlength="3" maxlength="30" class="form-control" value ="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($email) ?>" required>
    </div>

    <div class="iamnotarobot">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="secret_key_here"></div>
    </div>
                        
    <button type="submit" name="send" class="form-button btn">1, 2, 3... LET'S GO!</button>
        <?php if (isset($captcha_validation)) { ?>
            <p class="validation-message"><?php echo $captcha_validation ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
</form>
```

formvalidation.php:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

    $userName = $_POST['name'];
    $userEmail = $_POST['email'];

    $to = "testform@maildrop.cc";
    $subject = "New Form Submission";
    $body = $userName.' wants to know when company_name will be launched! Be sure to email them at '.$userEmail.'.';

    #$headers = 'From:' .$email;

    $secretKey = "site_key_here";
    $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $UserIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey&remoteip=$UserIP";

    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $response = json_decode($response);

    if ($response->success)
    {
        mail($to, $subject, $body);
        #header("Location: index.php?mailsent");
        $captcha_validation = 'Message successfully sent!';
        $name = '';
        $email = '';
        include('index.php');
    } 
    else {
        #header("Location: index.php?invalidcaptcha");
        $captcha_validation = 'Invalid captcha. Message not sent.';
        include('index.php');
    }
 }   
?>
```

Comment: what debugging have you done?

Comment: *header location works (I think)*, commented out code won't execute

Comment: I commented it out temporarily so the validation message would work. I just left it there to show my placement.

Comment: comment out mail(), narrow it down by debuggin the $_POST for expected values, then check captcha is true (or false test both). then it only leaves mail(). also you shouldn't output after setting the redirect header as the user is not going to see it.